# armv8 NEON if condition

Tags: if-statement, arm, overflow, conditional-statements, neon

I would like to realize if condition in armv8 NEON inline assembly code. 
In armv7 this was possible through checking overflow bit like this:

```
  VMRS r4, FPSCR            
  BIC r4, r4, #(1<<27)      
  VMSR FPSCR, r4     

  vtst.16  d30, d30, d30    
  vqadd.u16  d30, d30, d30 

  vmrs r4, FPSCR            
  tst  r4, #(1<<27)         
  bne label1
```

But I am not able to achieve this in armv8 equivalent code. It seems that SQADD doesnt affect overflow bit in FPSR or I cannot check it like this. Is it possible or is there better approach how to skip long part of code?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "overflow bit in FPCR"? FPCR is the control register; status bits are in FPSR. What's your A64 code doing currently?

Comment: I meant FPSR. My code is doing something like: load pixels from image into NEON register, do some computation on this register, then check if at least one pixel is not 0. If this condition is true, than do a lot of instructions on this NEON register. Otherwise continue with new load...

Comment: Well, the pseudocode in the ARM ARM for `sqadd` certainly says it sets FPSR.QC if saturation occurs. Of course, looking again at the A32 code, if you're expecting -1 + -1 to overflow a _signed_ type, that's a different matter...

Comment: Is this as simple as you looking for `UQADD` rather than `SQADD`? Your AArch32 code uses `vqadd.u16`, i.e. looking for unsigned saturation rather than signed saturation.

Comment: Show us what you tried with ARMv8 code

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I would like to do the same (check if at least one pixel is not 0). On ARMv7-a, I was doing vcmp.f64 d30, #0; vmrs APSR_nzcv, fpscr; beq .jump. What would be the equivalent on ARMV8-a?

Comment: Yes, I used the same approach as for arm v7, try it
  "MRS x5, FPSR                    
  "BIC x5, x5, #(1<<27)           
  "MSR FPSR, x5                  

  "CMTST  v1.16B, v1.16B, v1.16B      
  "UQADD    v1.16B, v1.16B, v1.16B     
  "mrs x4, FPSR                 

  "tst  x4, #(1<<27)                

  "beq label2

Answer (score 1):

The same information is available in Aarch64. You just need to replace:

`VMSR r4, FPSCR
VMRS FPSCR, r4`

by:

`MRS w4, FPSR
MSR FPSR, w4`