# armv8-a: test if SIMD register is != 0

Tags: assembly, arm, 64-bit, neon

It's a question very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145583/armv8-neon-if-condition).

On armv7-a, I have the following assembly code:

```
vcmp.f64 d0, #0
vmrs APSR_nzcv, fpscr
beq .jumpover
```

How can I convert this code to armv8-a? I want to test if there is any non-zero pixel in v0.16b.

**EDIT #1**

I was thinking about something like:

```
addv b0, v0.16b
fcmp s0, #0.0
beq .jumpover
```

Is this correct? Also, I read the following statement "Floating point FCMP and FCCMP instructions set the integer condition flags directly, and do not modify the condition flags in the FPSR." which I'm not 100% sure to understand.

Comment: Please see https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/41836-102-1-229511/ARM.Reference_Manual.pdf.  Lools like you want data movement instructions. You could   umov w2,v0.8b[1]  then cmp w2, #0

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense since you're describing data in an integer data format, but talk about performing a floating point comparison.

Comment: ADDV <V>d, Vn.<T>
Integer sum elements to scalar (vector). Where <V>/<T> is B/8B, B/16B, H/4H, H/8H, S/2S, or S/4S.

Comment: @Ross Ridge, my code works on armv7-a. I load 8 bytes into d0 and then the vector is compared as a floating point (64bit). Read the armv7-a specs.

Comment: @InfinitelyManiac, ADDV sums all the lanes so if one pixel is non-zero, b0 is going to be different from zero. Then, I'm not completeley sure how to compare the result.

Comment: @gregoiregentil - I was primarily pointing out that ADDV is for integers but your second instruction is for floating points. I am currently looking at  cmeq v1.8b, v0.8b, #0; which will show which element in v0 is eq to 0 by placing a (-1) in destination vector v1; however, I haven't found an simd instruction that changes cpsr.

Comment: @InfinitelyManiac, Yes, I'm unsure how to compare b0 to #0. The problem of cmeq and equivalent is that you stay inside the SIMD v"something".8b and you can't extract the comparison bit. I only see ADDV to help but perhaps I'm missing a better instruction.

Comment: Surely this is just `mov x0, v0.d[0] ; cmp x0, #0 ; beq .jumpover`?

Comment: Compare against floating-point 0 works except that `-0.0 == +0.0` in IEEE FP math, so your code will have a false-positive detection of all-zero when the high bit of the highest pixel is `1` but all the other bits are zero.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format.  The high bit is the sign bit.  Also, `s0` is a 32-bit register; you said you compared as 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sh1 in the comments found a working solution:

```
mov x0, v0.d[0]
cmp x0, #0
beq .jumpover

mov x0, v0.d[1]
cmp x0, #0
beq .jumpover
```

You have to do it for both d[0] and d[1] to check the 16 pixels.

Comment: Yeah - that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Need to check cycles for smov w1, v1.h[0]; which is a single SIMD element  move to general register.

```
    data                                                                                                                                                                   
array:  .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0                                                                                      
    .text                                                                                                                                                                   
            .global main                                                                                                                                                    

    main:                                                                                                                                                                   
            ldr x20,=array                  // array pointer                                                                                                                
            ld1 {v0.8b}, [x20]              // just for eg.,                                                                                                  
            cmgt v1.8b, v0.8b, #0           // any non-zero values ?                                                                                                        
            addv b1, v1.8b                  // vector reduce across lanes - element 0 in all sizes will hold some value :: conjecture                                       
            smov w1, v1.h[0]                // sign or unsigned - don't matter - index 0 will have some value   - check cycles                                              
            cmp w1, #0                      //                                                                                                                              
            cset w1, ne                     // just to test - (branch)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion something. I have done something like that on armv7-a but I think it's completely inefficient. Because you pay the price to extract from SIMD data 8 times and then you compare each time. I'm not a neon expert but I was told that it's super expensive.

Comment: Oh I see.  Yes, moving between regular registers and SIMD register may get expensive. Please review the Vector Arithmetic section starting on page 111. There are some vector compare masks that may be what you want. I'll delete my Answer.